# Получить перемещение телефона в пространстве

Tags: c#, android

Пытаюсь получить перемещение телефона, но почему-то всегда возвращается только NaN, кто-нибудь с этим сталкивался? (сам mOrientation прекрасно инициализируется, но вот значения изменений почему-то не отдает)

```
[Activity(Label = "MotionDetector", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity, ISensorEventListener
    {
        private static readonly object _syncLock = new object();
        private SensorManager _sensorManager;
        private Sensor mOrientation;
        private TextView _sensorTextView;
        float az, pitch, roll;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            _sensorManager = (SensorManager)GetSystemService(SensorService);
            _sensorTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.accelerometer_text);

        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            mOrientation = _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Orientation);
            _sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, mOrientation, SensorDelay.Normal);

        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            _sensorManager.UnregisterListener(this);
        }

        public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, SensorStatus accuracy)
        {
            //
        }

        public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
        {
            lock (_syncLock)
            {

                if (e.Sensor.Type == SensorType.Orientation)
                {
                    az = e.Values[0];
                    pitch = e.Values[1];
                    roll = e.Values[2]; 
                    _sensorTextView.Text = Convert.ToString(roll+az+pitch);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А на чем это вы, простите, пишете вообще?

Comment: Xamarin походу

Comment: >А на чем это вы, простите, пишете вообще?
А как же теги посмотреть? там явно стоит тег C#, на C# пишу, используя Xamarin.